# Layout Folder name for 7" Tablet

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources

I have two layout folders, `layout-sw600dp` for 7" Tablet (1024X600) mdpi and another with name `layout-xlarge` for 12" Tablet (1280X800) mdpi. The problem is that when I run my project in 7" emulator it pics the layout from `layout-xlarge` folder instead of `layout-sw600dp`. I have also tried other solutions by changing folder names which are given in different sites but could not find the suitable solution for my problem. Please provide me a working solution for this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The thing to remember here is that using the `swXXXdp` resource identifier only works on devices that are running Android 3.2+ (which is when it was added). Older devices will not recognize and therefore will not use these identifiers, so you must use the old identifiers (`small`, `normal`, `large`, `xlarge`) if you intend on supporting tablets running Android < 3.2. As of now, only 0.3% of tablets out there run Android 3.1 (API 12), so it's a safe call to not fully support them - http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html.

There is an excellent blog explaining how to use these newer resource identifiers.
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html

For your particular issue, assuming you are only supporting Android 3.2+ for your tablet layouts, change your `layout-xlarge` folder to `layout-sw720dp` to support 10"+ tablets, and your `layout-sw600dp` will support 7" tablet layouts.

Comment: Steven Byle Sir Thanks a lot I changed my Emulator API level to 13 and it worked. There is a little problem when I run my project in Nexus(7.27") because it also uses layout-w600dp but its resolution is tvdpi(800X1280) so some UI elements are not displaying properly.

Answer (score 1):

The options for layout folders are vast. Not only can you specify things like `layout-land/` or `layout-large`, you can also specify mixtures of them, like `layout-large-land/` or `layout-xhdpi-land/`. You can see all of the qualifiers [here at Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers). 
For your problem, check to see if the dimensions of your tablet emulator is of the correct screen resolution. You can specify a specific screen resolution when creating an AVD. Also, when specifying `layout-sw600dp/`, it checks for the width of the actual available width of your currently running actiity. On tablets running 4.2, for instance, ~50dp of the bottom of the screen is used for the system bar, and some are used for the top action bar if not in fullscreen. These would reduce the actual dp to less than 600.